# Samsung p7510 versus p5110 : what are the main differences?

Tags: tablet, samsung

I'm in a tight schedule to buy someone a tablet in the ipad2-range, but I want to buy an Android device.

After some research I decided to buy the Samsung Tab  10.1" P5110 (I don't need 3G).  However the Samsung Tab 10.1" p7510 is much easier to find in a short term.  When comparing both I got a bit confused because I don't get the main differences between both models.

Is there an obvious 'best one' ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`P5110`](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=specs&id=3448&c=samsung_gt-p5110_galaxy_tab_2_10.1_wifi_16gb) is the Galaxy Tab 2 while [`P7510`](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=specs&id=2936&c=samsung_gt-p7510_galaxy_tab_10.1_wi-fi_16gb) is the original. The difference is that the newer ships with ICS and has a different SoC along with a slightly larger battery, while it is a lightly ticker. The `P7510` came out almost a year ago.

If you want future software upgrades the `P5110` is a safer bet. See that datasheets for more info.